# Crystal Reports: Running Total of a Group

Tags: crystal-reports

I have running total of a group, works fine but doesn't reset after every group.

My group header Formula:

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar SUM_A:=0;
numbervar SUM_B:=0;
```

Next I have a suppressed formula in the Details section:

```
if ({REPORT_DATA.A} = "Y") then 
    (shared numbervar SUM_A:=SUM_A+{REPORT_DATA.SUM_OF_A};)
else if ({REPORT_DATA.BM} = "Y") then 
    (shared numbervar SUM_B:=SUM_B+{REPORT_DATA.B};)
```

In the group footer I have several formulas as such:

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar SUM_A;
SUM_A;
```

Up to here everything works fine and the numbers add up. However, when the report continues and the second group begins, the SUM variable **does not get reset** (my understand is that it should because of the formula in the group header).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Either your SUM_A variables are not the same or they are not being evaluated in a consistent way.  Try the following:

Firstly, declare the variables consistently as either:
Shared numbervar sum_a; or
Numbervar sum_a;
... These are declarations for two different variables!  Only add 'shared' if variables are being used in subreports and the main report.

Secondly, if you are using whileprintingrecords you generally need that in the other formulas working on those variables.  So, add whileprintingrecords to the top of the other formulas with sum_a variables.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this didn't work.

I solved the issue by putting the formula field that zeros out the totals AFTER they have been displayed, in the group footer.